# ¿cómo hacer peticiones HTTP concatenadas en Ionic o Angular?

Tags: api, http, ionic-framework, observable

Tengo una duda del uso de observables en Ionic o Angular. Tengo un servidor con mi backend y tengo una tabla que se rellena con info de otras 3; por ejemplo: la tabla Lugar que referencia a País, Departamento y Ciudad.
Quiero con HTTP, primero saber si existen el País, Departamento y Ciudad dados en las tablas y si existen obtener sus Ids. Si no existen agregarlos y obtener sus IDs (puede que exista el país pero no la Ciudad, por ejemplo). Y con esos IDs lo mismo para Lugar, ver si existe primero y si no agregarlo. Lugar tiene otros campos como nombre y descripció, latitude y longitud, etc.

Use el forkJoin para concatenar las 3 primeras subscripciones pero no sé como condicionarla y concatenarlas.
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo, preguntas como recomendaciones o como hago esto, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad ,consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Es que no he programado nada al respecto.